# hadoop job -kill <ID> fails to kill

Tags: java, hadoop

I am using version 1.0.4. There are some jobs which has been hanging, so I have been trying to kill the jobs to release the sources... However, killing command doesnt seem to work... Here is what I am doing:

```
hadoop job -list

JobId   State   StartTime   UserName    Priority    SchedulingInfo
job_1   1   1473112865969   xyz            NORMAL   NA

hadoop job -kill job_1
Killed job job_2
```

And after this, I run the list command again, and the killed job is still there:

```
hadoop job -list

JobId   State   StartTime   UserName    Priority    SchedulingInfo
job_1   1   1473112865969   xyz            NORMAL   NA
```

I have googled the issue, but couldnt find anything other than some unanswered forum entries.

Anyone else had similar issue on hadoop to kill jobs? Are there any other way to kill  a running job on hadoop for the version 1.0.4 ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, after digging the code and cluster for few hours, found out that the disk which was used to mrlocal directories had failure (i.e not accessible), so tasktracker has stopped with 0 error logs... After changing the mrlocal directories on the cluster and restarting the trackers, everything was back to normal, and all of the hanging jobs were killed automatically on restart...

Answer (score 1):

The command you are firing seems correct to me, only thing I am suspecting is the user privileges, may be the user you are using to kill the job doesn't have enough permission.

Also you are killing job_1 from the command and in response it is saying killed job_2.

hadoop job -kill job_1
Killed job job_2

Answer (score 1):

Try using below commands

`mapred job -list`

`mapred job -kill $jobId`

`yarn application -list`

`yarn application -kill $jobId`